# NEW Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit

Tags: contract-development, ethers.js, nodejs, flashbots

**The following error appears**

> Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit (error={"reason":"processing response error","code":"SERVER_ERROR","body":"{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":45,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"execution reverted"}}","error":{"code":-32000},"requestBody":"{"method":"eth_estimateGas","params":[{"from":"0x4209c9ea64fb4fa437eb950b3839a43c99d96c06","to":"0x5eeaa2dcb23056f4e8654a349e57ebe5e76b5e6e","data":"0xa9059cbb0000000000000000000000006232a23425f132c4fbe49dd1bdb9e872403a1cc90000000000000000000000000000000000000000000054b40b1f852bda000000"}],"id":45,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}","requestMethod":"POST","url":"https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/7ff28c44784b4d3d97e169bc155675eb"}, method="estimateGas", transaction={"from":"0x4209C9eA64fb4fA437eb950B3839a43C99d96c06","to":"0x5EeAA2DCb23056F4E8654a349E57eBE5e76b5e6e","data":"0xa9059cbb0000000000000000000000006232a23425f132c4fbe49dd1bdb9e872403a1cc90000000000000000000000000000000000000000000054b40b1f852bda000000","accessList":null}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=providers/5.4.3)

```js
import {
  FlashbotsBundleProvider, FlashbotsBundleRawTransaction,
  FlashbotsBundleResolution,
  FlashbotsBundleTransaction
} from "@flashbots/ethers-provider-bundle";
import { BigNumber, providers, Wallet } from "ethers";
import { Base } from "./engine/Base";
import {TransferERC20}  from "./engine/TransferERC20";
import { checkSimulation, gasPriceToGwei, printTransactions } from "./utils";
import { Approval721 } from "./engine/Approval721";

require('log-timestamp');

const BLOCKS_IN_FUTURE = 2;

const GWEI = BigNumber.from(10).pow(9);
const PRIORITY_GAS_PRICE = GWEI.mul(31)

const PRIVATE_KEY_EXECUTOR = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_EXECUTOR
const PRIVATE_KEY_SPONSOR = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_SPONSOR
const FLASHBOTS_RELAY_SIGNING_KEY = process.env.FLASHBOTS_RELAY_SIGNING_KEY
const RECIPIENT = process.env.RECIPIENT


if (PRIVATE_KEY_EXECUTOR === "") {
  console.warn("Must provide PRIVATE_KEY_EXECUTOR environment variable, corresponding to Ethereum EOA with assets to be transferred")
  process.exit(1)
}
if (PRIVATE_KEY_SPONSOR === "") {
  console.warn("Must provide PRIVATE_KEY_SPONSOR environment variable, corresponding to an Ethereum EOA with ETH to pay miner")
  process.exit(1)
}
if (FLASHBOTS_RELAY_SIGNING_KEY === "") {
  console.warn("Must provide FLASHBOTS_RELAY_SIGNING_KEY environment variable. Please see https://github.com/flashbots/pm/blob/main/guides/flashbots-alpha.md")
  process.exit(1)
}
if (RECIPIENT === "") {
  console.warn("Must provide RECIPIENT environment variable, an address which will receive assets")
  process.exit(1)
}

async function main() {
  const walletRelay = new Wallet(FLASHBOTS_RELAY_SIGNING_KEY)

  // ======= UNCOMMENT FOR GOERLI ==========
  // const provider = new providers.InfuraProvider(5, process.env.INFURA_API_KEY || '');
  // const flashbotsProvider = await FlashbotsBundleProvider.create(provider, walletRelay, 'https://relay-goerli.epheph.com/');
  // ======= UNCOMMENT FOR GOERLI ==========

  // ======= UNCOMMENT FOR MAINNET ==========
  const ETHEREUM_RPC_URL = process.env.ETHEREUM_RPC_URL || "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/7ff28c44784b4d3d97e169bc155675eb"
  const provider = new providers.StaticJsonRpcProvider(ETHEREUM_RPC_URL);
  const flashbotsProvider = await FlashbotsBundleProvider.create(provider, walletRelay);
  // ======= UNCOMMENT FOR MAINNET ==========

  const walletExecutor = new Wallet(PRIVATE_KEY_EXECUTOR);
  const walletSponsor = new Wallet(PRIVATE_KEY_SPONSOR);

  const block = await provider.getBlock("latest")

  // ======= UNCOMMENT FOR ERC20 TRANSFER ==========
  const tokenAddress = "0x5EeAA2DCb23056F4E8654a349E57eBE5e76b5e6e";
  const engine: Base = new TransferERC20(provider, walletExecutor.address, RECIPIENT, tokenAddress);
  // ======= UNCOMMENT FOR ERC20 TRANSFER ==========

  // ======= UNCOMMENT FOR 721 Approval ==========
   //const HASHMASKS_ADDRESS = "0x082903f4e94c5e10a2b116a4284940a36afaed63";
   //const engine: Base = new Approval721(RECIPIENT, [HASHMASKS_ADDRESS]);
  // ======= UNCOMMENT FOR 721 Approval ==========

  const sponsoredTransactions = await engine.getSponsoredTransactions();

  const gasEstimates = await Promise.all(sponsoredTransactions.map(tx =>
    provider.estimateGas({
      ...tx,
      from: tx.from === undefined ? walletExecutor.address : tx.from
    }))
  )
  const gasEstimateTotal = gasEstimates.reduce((acc, cur) => acc.add(cur), BigNumber.from(0))

  const gasPrice = PRIORITY_GAS_PRICE.add(block.baseFeePerGas || 0);
  const bundleTransactions: Array<FlashbotsBundleTransaction | FlashbotsBundleRawTransaction> = [
    {
      transaction: {
        to: walletExecutor.address,
        gasPrice: gasPrice,
        value: gasEstimateTotal.mul(gasPrice),
        gasLimit: 100000,
      },
      signer: walletSponsor
    },
    ...sponsoredTransactions.map((transaction, txNumber) => {
      return {
        transaction: {
          ...transaction,
          gasPrice: gasPrice,
          gasLimit: gasEstimates[txNumber],
        },
        signer: walletExecutor,
      }
    })
  ]
  const signedBundle = await flashbotsProvider.signBundle(bundleTransactions)
  await printTransactions(bundleTransactions, signedBundle);
  const simulatedGasPrice = await checkSimulation(flashbotsProvider, signedBundle);

  console.log(await engine.description())

  console.log(`Executor Account: ${walletExecutor.address}`)
  console.log(`Sponsor Account: ${walletSponsor.address}`)
  console.log(`Simulated Gas Price: ${gasPriceToGwei(simulatedGasPrice)} gwei`)
  console.log(`Gas Price: ${gasPriceToGwei(gasPrice)} gwei`)
  console.log(`Gas Used: ${gasEstimateTotal.toString()}`)

  provider.on('block', async (blockNumber) => {
    const simulatedGasPrice = await checkSimulation(flashbotsProvider, signedBundle);
    const targetBlockNumber = blockNumber + BLOCKS_IN_FUTURE;
    console.log(`Current Block Number: ${blockNumber},   Target Block Number:${targetBlockNumber},   gasPrice: ${gasPriceToGwei(simulatedGasPrice)} gwei`)
    const bundleResponse = await flashbotsProvider.sendBundle(bundleTransactions, targetBlockNumber);
    if ('error' in bundleResponse) {
      throw new Error(bundleResponse.error.message)
    }
    const bundleResolution = await bundleResponse.wait()
    if (bundleResolution === FlashbotsBundleResolution.BundleIncluded) {
      console.log(`Congrats, included in ${targetBlockNumber}`)
      process.exit(0)
    } else if (bundleResolution === FlashbotsBundleResolution.BlockPassedWithoutInclusion) {
      console.log(`Not included in ${targetBlockNumber}`)
    } else if (bundleResolution === FlashbotsBundleResolution.AccountNonceTooHigh) {
      console.log("Nonce too high, bailing")
      process.exit(1)
    }
  })
}

main()
```

Comment: have you tried to adjust your gasLimit? this one gasLimit: 100000,

Comment: I tried both gas limit and 21000 and 100000. There is no difference.